# get the nth-lowest value in a `group by` clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's a tough one: I have data coming back in a temporary table `foo` in this form:

```
id   n    v
--   -    -
1    3    1
1    3    10
1    3    100
1    3    201
1    3    300
2    1    13
2    1    21
2    1    300
4    2    1
4    2    7
4    2    19
4    2    21
4    2    300
8    1    11
```

Grouping by `id`, I need to get the row with the nth-lowest value for `v` based on the value in `n`. For example, for the group with an ID of 1, I need to get the row which has `v` equal to 100, since 100 is the third-lowest value for `v`.

Here's what the final results need to look like:

```
id   n    v
--   -    -
1    3    100
2    1    13
4    2    7
8    1    11
```

Some notes about the data:

- the number of rows for each ID may vary
- `n` will always be the same for every row with a given ID
- `n` for a given ID will never be greater than the number of rows with that ID
- the data will already be sorted by `id`, then `v`

Bonus points if you can do it in generic SQL instead of oracle-specific stuff, but that's not a requirement (I suspect that `rownum` may factor prominently in any solutions). It has in my attempts, but I wind up confusing myself before I get a working solution.

Comment: ....this should be a standard [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query (where you need the nth row instead of up-to-n), but it's not clear what you're using to get `n` in the first place (some better solutions may be available if we go back to the source tables).  Also, you say you need the "nth highest", but your actual data seems to be "nth lowest".

Comment: You state "nth highest" and then give results for "nth lowest".

Comment: @MatBailie: not sure what you mean?

Comment: Of the values for id=2, the 1st highest is 300, not 13, which is the lowest...

Comment: @MatBailie: whoops yep, I'll fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `row_number` function make row number the compare with `n` column value in `CTE`, do another `CTE` to make row number order by `v` desc.

get `rn = 1` which is mean max value in the `n` number group.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
   id int,
   n int,
   v int
);


insert into foo values (1,3,1);
insert into foo values (1,3,10);
insert into foo values (1,3,100);
insert into foo values (1,3,201);
insert into foo values (1,3,300);
insert into foo values (2,1,13);
insert into foo values (2,1,21);
insert into foo values (2,1,300);
insert into foo values (4,2,1);
insert into foo values (4,2,7);
insert into foo values (4,2,19);
insert into foo values (4,2,21);
insert into foo values (4,2,300);
insert into foo values (8,1,11);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as(
    select id,n,v 
    from
    (
        select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id ,n order by n) as rn
        from foo t
    ) t1 
    where rn <= n
), maxcte as (
    select id,n,v, row_number() over(partition by id ,n order by v desc) rn 
    from cte 
)
select id,n,v 
from maxcte
where rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e034/1/0)**:

```
| ID | N |   V |
|----|---|-----|
|  1 | 3 | 100 |
|  2 | 1 |  13 |
|  4 | 2 |   7 |
|  8 | 1 |  11 |
```

Comment: Value needed isn't necessarily the maximum!

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks!

Comment: TO THOSE LOOKING FOR A SOLUTION: I marked this one as correct since it was the first that worked properly, but I like Zaynul's solution better since it's simpler (once it was fixed). And if you can guarantee you'll always be using Oracle 12.1+, Werfried's solution is even simpler.

Answer (score 2):

use window function

```
select * from
(
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id ,n order by v) as rn
from foo  t
 ) t1 
 where t1.rn=t1.n
```

as ops sample output just need 3rd highest value so i put where condition t1.rn=3 though accodring to description it would be t1.rn=t1.n

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=65abf8d4101d2d1802c1a05ed82c9064

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179588/discussion-on-answer-by-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-get-the-nth-highest-value-in-a-grou).

Answer (score 2):

If your database is version 12.1 or higher then there is a much simpler solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, n, NTH_VALUE(v,n) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS v
FROM foo
ORDER BY ID;


| ID | N |   V |
|----|---|-----|
|  1 | 3 | 100 |
|  2 | 1 |  13 |
|  4 | 2 |   7 |
|  8 | 1 |  11 |
```

Depending on your real data you may have to add an `ORDER BY n` clause and/or windowing_clause as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, see [NTH_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions126.htm#SQLRF30031)

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, our production DB is still 11.x but it works in our other environments.